# Swift: Expected ',' failures?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I am kind of new at programming, and i followed an guide step by step, everything worked fine, but at this point i am stuck. I have checked everything, but it said that there was failures every time i tried to fix it and build it would come up with failures, such as `Expected expressions in list of expressions` , `Expected ',' separator` and `'()' is not convertible to 'Orientation'`

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

let NumOrientations: UInt32 = 4

enum Orientation: Int, Printable {
    case Zero = 0, Ninety, OneEighty, TwoSeventy

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Zero:
            return "0"
        case .Ninety:
            return "90"
        case .OneEighty:
            return "180"
        case .TwoSeventy:
            return "270"
        }
    }

    static func random() -> Orientation {
        return Orientation.fromRaw(<#Int#>(arc4random_uniform(NumOrientations)))
    }

// #1
    static func rotate(orientation:Orientation, clockwise: Bool) -> Orientation {
        var rotated = orientation.toRaw() + (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
        if rotated > Orientation.TwoSeventy.toRaw() {
            rotated = Orientation.Zero.toRaw()
        } else if rotated < 0 {
            rotated = Orientation.TwoSeventy.toRaw()
        }
        return Orientation.fromRaw(rotated)!
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: I don't know Swift but this line is obviously a problem: `return Orientation.fromRaw(<#Int#>(arc4random_uniform(NumOrientations)))`.

Comment: You know, it would really be helpful if you told us what line the error occurred on.

Comment: The <#Int#> is text Xcode inserts to help with autocompletion in the IDE. Typically you'd tab and it'd select that text block (and it'd say Int), and you type over it. That definitely needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you got the <#Int#> syntax from, but this works for me:

```
static func random() -> Orientation! {  
    return Orientation.fromRaw(Int(arc4random_uniform(NumOrientations)))
}
```

Note that the return type should be `Orientation!`, not `Orientation` as it isn't an optional.

Similarly for your `rotate` function

```
static func rotate(orientation:Orientation, clockwise: Bool) -> Orientation! {
    var rotated = orientation.toRaw() + (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
    if rotated > Orientation.TwoSeventy.toRaw() {
        rotated = Orientation.Zero.toRaw()
    } else if rotated < 0 {
        rotated = Orientation.TwoSeventy.toRaw()
    }
    return Orientation.fromRaw(rotated)
}
```

Note that you can make the rotate function an instance method rather than static, which is better object-oriented design

```
func rotate(#clockwise:Bool) -> Orientation! {
    var rotated = self.toRaw() + (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
    if rotated > Orientation.TwoSeventy.toRaw() {
        rotated = Orientation.Zero.toRaw()
    } else if rotated < 0 {
        rotated = Orientation.TwoSeventy.toRaw()
    }
    return Orientation.fromRaw(rotated)
}
```